# How to give unique ids to divs as they are writen to page with php

Tags: php

Im using php to create a string using data submited on the previous page via a form using post.

**This is the php:**

```
if ($carrier== "DL") {   


                $front = '<tr><td><div onclick="selectText(this)">EZE*#$*IET';
                $center =  '/O$'.$FOP.'/RB'.$differencePos.'X0.00P'.$fee.'AT0.00/OIECP'.$orIssue.'111062789#MCRV*/MA'.$MCOamt; 
                $end = '</div></td></tr>';


                               echo $front,$guest1Ticket,'X*A',$guest1Con,$center,'#N1.1',$end;

             if($guest2Ticket) echo $front,$guest2Ticket,'X*A',$guest2Con,$center,'#N2.1',$end;  

             if($guest3Ticket) echo $front,$guest3Ticket,'X*A',$guest3Con,$center,'#N3.1',$end;  

             if($guest4Ticket) echo $front,$guest4Ticket,'X*A',$guest4Con,$center,'#N4.1',$end;  

             if($guest5Ticket) echo $front,$guest5Ticket,'X*A',$guest5Con,$center,'#N5.1',$end;  

             if($guest6Ticket) echo $front,$guest6Ticket,'X*A',$guest6Con,$center,'#N6.1',$end;  

             if($guest7Ticket) echo $front,$guest7Ticket,'X*A',$guest7Con,$center,'#N7.1',$end;  

             if($guest8Ticket) echo $front,$guest8Ticket,'X*A',$guest8Con,$center,'#N8.1',$end;  

             if($guest9Ticket) echo $front,$guest9Ticket,'X*A',$guest9Con,$center,'#N9.1',$end; 
        } //if ($airline == "DL")
```

**This will create strings that look like this:**
`EZE*#$*IET8388623729002X*A/O$CA/RB71.02X0.00P50.00AT0.00/OIECP01AUG111062789#MCRV*/MA21.02#N1.1`

`EZE*#$*IET8388623729003X*A/O$CA/RB71.02X0.00P50.00AT0.00/OIECP01AUG111062789#MCRV*/MA21.02#N2.1`

`EZE*#$*IET8388623729004X*A/O$CA/RB71.02X0.00P50.00AT0.00/OIECP01AUG111062789#MCRV*/MA21.02#N3.1`

`....`

The only difference between each line is the IET **8388623729004** parts and the N **1.1** parts on the ends of the strings themselves.

Im using the `$front` and `$end` substrings to wrap the actual strings in div and table elements for layout purposes.

**What would be the best way to give each of the divs that gets echo'd out a unique id so  my `onclick="selectText(this)"` will work?**

I know I could break `$front` into several substrings and just do something like

`if($guest2Ticket) echo $front1,'id="div2"',$front2,$guest2Ticket,'X*A',$guest2Con,$center,'#N2.1',$end;`

but is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way I would do it. By changing `$front` from a variable string to a function, you can use a static counter and increase it every time you call the function

```
function front() {
    static $i=1;
    return '<tr><td><div id="div'.$i.'" onclick="selectText(this)">EZE*#$*IET';
    $i++;
}
```

it would look something like this

```
if ($carrier== "DL") {   


            function front() {
                  static $i=1;
                  return '<tr><td><div id="div'.$i.'" onclick="selectText(this)">EZE*#$*IET';
                  $i++;
             }
            $center =  '/O$'.$FOP.'/RB'.$differencePos.'X0.00P'.$fee.'AT0.00/OIECP'.$orIssue.'111062789#MCRV*/MA'.$MCOamt; 
            $end = '</div></td></tr>';


                           echo front(),$guest1Ticket,'X*A',$guest1Con,$center,'#N1.1',$end;

         if($guest2Ticket) echo front(),$guest2Ticket,'X*A',$guest2Con,$center,'#N2.1',$end;  

         if($guest3Ticket) echo front(),$guest3Ticket,'X*A',$guest3Con,$center,'#N3.1',$end;  

         if($guest4Ticket) echo front(),$guest4Ticket,'X*A',$guest4Con,$center,'#N4.1',$end;  

         if($guest5Ticket) echo front(),$guest5Ticket,'X*A',$guest5Con,$center,'#N5.1',$end;  

         if($guest6Ticket) echo front(),$guest6Ticket,'X*A',$guest6Con,$center,'#N6.1',$end;  

         if($guest7Ticket) echo front(),$guest7Ticket,'X*A',$guest7Con,$center,'#N7.1',$end;  

         if($guest8Ticket) echo front(),$guest8Ticket,'X*A',$guest8Con,$center,'#N8.1',$end;  

         if($guest9Ticket) echo front(),$guest9Ticket,'X*A',$guest9Con,$center,'#N9.1',$end; 
} //if ($airline == "DL")
```

Comment: Obviously, there is more to my code than I've shown above. (I actually have a bunch of these "string makers" going) This method lends itself better to my particular use.  Thank you very much Sean!

Answer (score 1):

I would do this with jquery, not emitting ids at all.

(Dont forget to include jquery.js first).

```
<script>
  $(function()
  {
    $('div').click(function()
    {
      selectText(this);
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: You also get the text inside a div using var txt = $(this).text(); alert(txt); instead of selectText(this);

Comment: Or why not letting selectText have a string passed as argument, then you selectText($(this).text());